# Replace every item in an array with an empty item

Tags: ruby, arrays

This is admittedly a bit of an odd issue, but I need to basically empty every item in an array (but keep the item itself).

For instance, if I have this array: `[ 0, 5, 4, 7, 1 ]`

I need to change it to: `[ '', '', '', '', '']`

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3.

*Some charting software I'm using requires an array for labels and the only way to hide those labels is to make the corresponding items blank. Yes, lame.*

Comment: Has to be an in-place operation? (note that you lose referential transparency on whatever method does that)

Comment: Can you clarify "but keep the item itself"? Do you mean "I want to return the result of performing the function on a variable without changing the value of the underlying variable"? If so, see my answer below!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Enumerable#map` replaces every element with the result of calling a block:

```
array = [ 0, 5, 4, 7, 1 ]
array.map { '' }
#=> ['', '', '', '', '']
```

If you wanted to mutate the original (if I understand your question this is precisely what you do **NOT** want to do), then use `#map!`

```
array.map! { '' }
array
#=> ['', '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: There's also `Array.new(n, '')` and `Array.new(n) { '' }` (which version you use depends on what's happening to the array). And there's always `[''] * n` (which suffers from the same problems as `Array.new(n, '')`).

Comment: Also `[''] * n` will produce an `n` element array with every element being `''`. So `[''] * array.count` would give the same result (but is slightly less clean IMO).

Comment: Typical stackoverflow race condition ;)